# Python: Splitting a string twice to form a 2D list

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to split a log files into a 2D list. First list splits at every tag and then at the second level it is split at every newline. I get the string and split it to get the first, but when I loop through it to split it again I get the error at the bottom. I have looked and tried different stuff with no luck. It seems right to me but I am fairly new to python.

```
with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
     read_data = f.read().split('tag:         "')
f.closed

for i in read_data:
    print read_data[i].split()
```

Error:

```
File "parsing.py", line 6, in <module>
    print read_data[i].split()
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Clearly, `i` is not an index into `read_data`. How about `print i.split()`?

Comment: Each `i` from `read_data` is a string.

Comment: Incidentally, `f.closed` does nothing. That's not how you close a file, and in any case it closes automatically on leaving the `with` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
    data2D = [x.split() for x in f.read().split('tag:         "') ]
```

Comment: It's not a 2d list, where is the missing for y ... ?

Answer (score 0):

`read_data` is a list of strings. You then put each string of the list in turn into `i`. So far, so good. However, you then try to use `i` (which is a string) as an index. What you should do instead is:

```
print i.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Version 2 of your code:

Strings in Python are immutable. It means that they can never change - you can only make a new string with altered contents:

```
>>> x = "Foo\r\n"
>>> x
"Foo\r\n"
>>> x.rstrip("\r\n")
"Foo"
>>> x
"Foo\r\n"
```

As you can see `rstrip()` did not change the value of the string named `x`. Instead it returned an altered string. If you don't care about the previous value, you can just reassign the name `x` to the new one:

```
>>> x = x.rstrip("\r\n")
>>> x
"Foo"
```